# Error while trying to query Active Directory - Requires App Pool recycling

Tags: iis, active-directory, application-pool

I have the following chunk of code in a .NET web app used to query AD for a user

```
using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ldap))
{
    using (DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de))
    {
        adSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(samAccountName=username))";
        SearchResult adSearchResult = adSearch.FindOne();
    }
}
```

When I run this, I sometimes get the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80005000): Unknown
>   error (0x80005000)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean
>   findMoreThanOne)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()

When this error is being thrown, it errors every time it runs. To correct this, I have to go to the IIS App Pool associated with this web app and recycle it. After recycling, the code works ... for a period of time. Then the error comes back a few hours later.

Additional information to note:

- The App Pool is still running when it errors. Still, recycling 
  fixes it
- I have this same code running on 2 different web servers that are identically configured. This issue occurs on the first web server but
  never on the second
- The App Pool is running under an AD service account. The same account is used on the app pool of both servers
- I have tried recreating the App Pool associated with this web app without success

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on where to look in IIS for a permanent solution. I can't be recycling the app pool every few hours.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to get a network trace when this happens and/or flip on ADSI tracing in Windows. I wonder if you are getting referred to a domain controller that is down or inaccessible.

Comment: @BrianDesmond, thanks, I'll take a look at that. The problem is, I never know when it's going to go down again. As for the DC, I'm not sure, but given that web server 2 continues to work, and they're both on the same subnet, I'd be skeptical. But will poke around and see what I can find.

Comment: I have this same issue. I tried turning on ADSI tracing which records events when I don't get the COM exception but when the error occurs the trace records nothing.

Comment: Ever get this figured out?

Comment: I answered a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36259818/intermittent-unknown-error-from-active-directory/57789441#57789441